# AWS ActionPutLogEvents is not visible in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am working on a StateMachine in AWS. I wanted to use the action **CloudWatch Logs:PutLogEvents** to make a custom log entry.

Here is the content of the API parameters of the action

```
{
  "LogEvents": [
    {
      "Message": "My message",
      "Timestamp": 1396035378988
    }
  ],
  "LogGroupName": "/aws/vendedlogs/states/MyStateMachine-wc8i8hnaf-Logs",
  "LogStreamName": "MyStream"
}
```

I fixed the issue about the permission to write on the Log Stream, and now the execution is done without error.

Anyway, I don't see my logs in CloudWatch.

Do you know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got it. the timestamp I generated was too old.
need to find a way to have a fresh one now :)